# Jquery to swap out certain links with a specific ID's using each

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me why this jquery does not work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('a').each(function(){
            jQuery("#get-pricing-now-button-hotfix8").attr("href", "/en/starting-prices/");
        });
    </script>
```

I have a few buttons on the page which have an id value of get-pricing-now-button-hotfix8 and I need the ahref value for those links switch to /en/starting-prices/.

I was able to get it working for one link using the following but only changes 1 single button.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#get-pricing-now-button-hotfix8").attr("href","/en/starting-prices/");
        });
    </script>
```

Please help!

Comment: IDs have to be unique. If you need multiple elements use classes

Comment: That `each` logic doesn't make much sense either

Comment: @charlietfl please expand. I am not a jquery expert. I have cobbled togther the above code based on what I have found in StackOverflow.

I just need jquery to loop through all the  instances of links assigned the #get-pricing-now-button-hotfix8 ID and then update the link for me.

The same way you would do in php foreach().

The second code works perfectly but on only the first instance of the link.

Thanks!

Comment: @cloned does this mean we need to put .get-pricing-now-button-hotfix8 instead?

Comment: Your logic is looping over all anchors in the page regardless of class and then every iteration changing all instances of that class regardless of what `<a>` is current instance in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @cloned for pointing me in the right direction.

In the end, I used this code and any instance to the new URL.

I changed #get-pricing-now-button-hotfix8 to .get-pricing-now-button-hotfix8 (changed from ID to class)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".get-pricing-now-button-hotfix8").attr("href","/en/starting-prices/");
    });
</script>
```